# What does session duration less than equal to 1 second signify in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, session

I was trying to segment my users on the basis of session duration which lies under 1 minute and when I used a filter of session duration less than equal to 1, it got set to session duration less than 1 second.

There I noticed a large set of my users and sessions lie in this segment. What could explain this scenario?

[image]

Comment: Less than a second is generally a bot or [bounces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounce_rate). [Event tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events) can also result in a duration of 1 second or less.

Comment: @dan I checked for the bots by applying this filter `Count of Visits = 1 && Visit Duration = 0 &&  Source exactly matches (direct) && Page Depth ≤ 1 && Gender does not match regex = male|female` referenced from http://parsnip.io/blog/detecting-bot-behavior-google-analytics/ and it shows that bots alone aren't the reason.

Comment: As I indicated, there are several possibilities, which would vary among sites.  Bots are certainly one possibility; as the link you reference points out, their duration could be zero, but they differ in terms of sophistication, with many now mimicking browsers since that article was written four years ago. Bounces are certainly another, as are events that might be triggered... There's really no way for us to be able to tell you why you're seeing this, since we don't know anything more about your site (e.g., is it engaging users, are there lots of inbound links from unrelated sites, etc...).

Comment: Initially you asked a general question that could be applicable to other sites and possibly helpful to future visitors. Your edit however affects existing answers and makes it too [specific to only your site](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), which is considered off-topic here. Again, there's really no way for us to know without knowing quite a bit more about your site. You'll need to spend some time analyzing your server logs to figure out the sources.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually fairly common on sites with a higher bounce rate and low pages per session given how Google calculates time by default. Here is a [more detailed explanation](http://paweljaniak.co.za/2013/05/12/0-second-visits/) (and that link includes solutions):

> when a somebody visits your page, Google Analytics will drop a
>   time-stamped cookie. When the same person visits another page on your
>   website (or refreshes) then Google Analytics will compare the
>   timestamp in the cookie to real time and will base the visit duration
>   on the first page on the difference between the two.
>
> If you have a high bounce rate where most of your visitors leave after
>   being on just one page of your website, there will be no second data
>   point for Google Analytics to calculate the duration and will default
>   to setting the visit duration as 0 seconds. This means that if someone
>   stays on your page for hours, or days even (they may leave the tab
>   with your website open), it will still record as 0 seconds if they
>   don’t visit a second page.

Comment: Yes I understand the concern but the scenario ain't exactly like this. This is from a platform which generates more than 1 million sessions a month with avg. pages per session = 7.3 and bounce rate of 40%. What are your thoughts @Matthew Edgar